# Calculations in minimum width

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm trying something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \newcommand{\mw}[1]{#1+1}
    \node [minimum width=\mw{1} cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My problem is that this is expanded to `1pt + 1cm`, but I want `2cm`.
The command `\mw` is simplified, the calculations are in fact more complex.

Any idea how i can achieve this?

EDIT: added parameter to command

EDIT2: What i actually want to do is some easy calculations for positioning

i defined two commands:

```
\newcommand{\col}[1]{#1 * 1.5}
\newcommand{\row}[1]{#1 * 1.1}

% and use it like this:
\node [minimum width=1.3cm] at (\col{2}, \row{3}) {};
```

It works like expected with the coordinates, but fails with minimum width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not 100% sure that I understand the intended application but the following (which defines alternative minimum width keys) may be of use:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  minimum width'/.code={%
    % Only advisable when x and y are orthogonal
    \pgfpointxy{#1}{0}%
    \tikzset{minimum width/.expanded=\the\csname pgf@x\endcsname}%
  },
  minimum width''/.style={minimum width=(#1)*1cm}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [minimum width=3+1,   draw] at (0,0) {A};
\node [minimum width'=3+1,  draw] at (0,1) {B};
\node [minimum width''=3+1, draw] at (0,2) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! the second one did exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Use `pgfmath` and do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mw}{1+1}
    \node [draw,minimum width=\mw cm] {};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mw}{2+2}
    \node [draw,minimum width=\mw cm,yshift=1cm] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is for the edit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\col}[1]{#1 * 1.5}
\newcommand{\row}[1]{#1 * 1.1}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mw}{\col{2}+\row{3}}
    \node [draw,minimum width=\mw cm,anchor=west] at (0,0){};
    \draw[yshift=-0.5cm,|-|] (0,0) -- node[midway,below]{6.3} (6.3,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One option is `\edef\mw{\number\numexpr 1+1\relax}` as in:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \edef\mw{\number\numexpr1+1\relax}
    \node [minimum width=\mw cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

- `\edef` stands for expandable macro definition, therefore the contents is expananded as `\mw` is defined.
- `\number` tries to convert the following expression to a number, and it's necessary because:
- `\numexpr` evaluates the following math expression, the expression should be with no spaces and ended by `\relax` (this is only one possibility, but the simplest one IMHO). The problem is that `\numexpr` itself wouldn't expand without being processed by something else, in this case, `\number` processes it.

Comment: I would also need parameters, `\newcommand{\mw}[1]{#1+1}`, is this also possible?

Comment: No, `\edef\mw#1{\number\numexpr #1+1\relax}` is the way to go then. `\newcommand can't be used, well, it can, but it doesn't seem safe. As well, this will work only with integers, so I suppose Harish's solution is better.

Comment: @HarishKumar i've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

After Mark Wibrows answer i found 3 possible (easy) solutions for my problem:

```
% 1.
\node [minimum width=(\col{1})*1cm] {};

% 2.
\newcommand{\helper}[1]{(#1)*1cm}
\node [minimum width=\helper{\col{1}}] {};

% 3.
\tikzset{%
    minimum widthCM/.style={minimum width=(#1)*1cm}
}
\node [minimum widthCM=\col{1}] {};
```