# Computing minimum width based on style arg

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

I have successfully defined a "block" that I can instantiate in various sizes, with annotations at its sides.  However, I would like to set the `minimum width` to `sqrt(#2)`, while keeping the label as `#2`.  Somehow, `\pgfmathresult` is always 0.4, and the resulting width is much too small (block becomes a vertical line):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  block/.code args={#1/#2}{
    \pgfmathparse{#2}
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/.cd,
      draw,
      inner sep=0pt, % make failing minimum width more obvious
      minimum height=#1,minimum width=\pgfmathresult, % minimum width=#2 works, but is too wide
      label={[rotate=90,anchor=south]west:#1},
      label={90:#2}}}
]

\node[block=36/1024] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I compute the `minimum width` to be `sqrt(#2)` (in pt units)?

Apparently, [Calculations in minimum width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/calculations-in-minimum-width) is really similar to my question, but I don't understand yet how to apply Mark's approach to my style definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should use `\pgfmathresult` immediately after setting it: other PGF routines might make use of the same feature. Indeed, at the end of the `tikzpicture`, the value of `\pgfmathresult` is 0.4, notwithstanding the setting you do. Use a specific macro:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  block/.code args={#1/#2}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\SQRTTWO{sqrt(#2)}
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/.cd,
      draw,
      inner sep=0pt, % make failing minimum width more obvious
      minimum height=#1,
      minimum width=\SQRTTWO, % minimum width=#2 works, but is too wide
      label={[rotate=90,anchor=south]west:#1},
      label={90:#2},
    },
  }
]
\node[block=36/1024] {};                    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact it is the `0.4pt` of the default line width selection most probably coming from the execution of the `draw` key.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I kind of knew the explanation (thanks, percusse, for pointing to `draw` as a likely culprit), and unsuccessfully tried to work around it using `\def` or `\edef`. `\pgfmathsetmacro` is the perfect answer I was looking for.